# Sending kafka broker logs to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, logging, apache-kafka, log4j

I have been working on storing apache-kafka broker logs into mysql database. Kafka has log4j jar file which has JDBC appender through that we can store logs directly into database. So I found log4j.properties file in kafka and tried to add JDBC properties lines in properties so it can send logs to database along with console and log file which is default logging feature in kafka

**log4j.properties:**
`

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, kafkaAppender, DB

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

#log4j JDBC appender properties I have added for storing logs in mysql database

log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=password
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO logs VALUES('%d', '%p', '%C', '%m')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n`
```

I have given half of the log4j.properties file here. The doubt is, I have added JDBC appender properties in the log4j.properties file but there is no logs get added in database when I started server and sending messages to brokers but I got console and file logs. Is this method right one or what is method or approach I have to use to get kafka broker logs appended in mysql database.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use an RDBMS for logs when something like Elasticsearch or Splunk is far more suited for that

Comment: I am learning on collecting logs and metrics from kafka broker right now and I also worked with Splunk where we can process logs to get different results. I just want to learn on how this thing log transfer thing works so I chose mysql so on further I can learn on how to process these data. I just want to know this log data transfer to mysql is possible or not?

Comment: It's just log4j, so, yes it's possible, assuming you put the jdbcappender and mysql jar into the classpath

Comment: Yes sir, I have tried an sample logger program with log4j and mysql maven dependency in IDE and the logs and storing in mysql database, but incase of kafka it is already generating logs in console and file so I thought of adding the jdbcappender property in log4j.properties file but after I have started server, publish and subscribed messages in producer and consumer nothing is appended in server but I am getting logs in console and files. So, is there any other way around do this logging thing with kafka

Comment: Well, I suggest isolating your issue. What happens when you remove `stdout, kafkaAppender` from the root appender? If something isn't working with the jdbc one, you should expect some errors from it

Comment: Thanks sir, It worked I don't know how this happened. Like before removing these two I don't got any exceptions regarding mysql or database but after removing these I got a error like password version change because I am using mysql 8.x but the driver version I used was 5.x, so I changed the password encryption method to mysql_native_password and after that I started the server I got all my logs fall into mysql database. Thank you so much sir. Sir, I want to mark this question as closed can you say how to do it, I am new to using stackoverflow.

Comment: You're welcome to put an answer below detailing the steps you took to solve the issue for future readers who may have the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the mysql connector v5 jar in KAFKA_HOME/lib and I have added jdbcappender property in log4j.properties file in KAFKA_HOME/config but on starting the kafka server and zookeeper server I didn't got any logs appended in mysql database so I just removed **stdout, kafkaAppender** in log4j.properties file so that I can see what is error causing the logs to not append in database. Finally got to know that mysql database I'm using is version 8 and mysql connector jar is version 5 and in version 8 the mysql authentication method is 'caching_sha2_password' so I changed that to 'mysql_native_password' method and then server logs got appended in mysql database.